# Homeomorphism between a line segment and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that is not a curve

Tags: general-topology

I was just wondering if there is a homeomorphism between the line segment $[0, 1]$ and a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that is not a curve. I would appreciate any eye-opening answers that would make it clear whether or not this is a possibility.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a "two dimensional region"? Would you be content with an answer given, say, a line segment and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @ Travis I just edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but are you looking for something like a space-filling curve?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: "Region" is vague. There are plenty of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ that are homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, and plenty that are not.

Comment: @ Nick D. This is precisely my point. I mean subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that are not subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NickD. You need to quantify this somehow. The top half of a circle is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$; does it count?

Comment: @Behrooz An open disk would work. If you remove a point from it, it is connected. This is not so for $[0,1]$.

Comment: what do you mean, exactly, by "it's not a curve"?

Comment: @ Abramo A curve is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I mean those subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that are not curves. Is is clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The usual *definition* of a curve is (the image of) a continuous map from $[0,1]\to\mathbf{R}^2$. If $[0,1]$ and a subset $S\subset\mathbf{R}^2$ are homeomorphic, then in particular $S$ is the image of the homeomorphism. So the answer to your question is no; any subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$ that is homeomorphic to an interval is in fact a curve.

Comment: Another problem! We know only _intuitively_ what a curve is---the continuous image of $[0, 1]$. So now that I look, it didn't solve the problem. In other words, I can accept your answer only _intuitively_.

Comment: so what is your definition of a curve?

Comment: My definition of curve is (probably) the same as yours: a continuous map $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (for a plane curve). But the thing is can you guarantee that all curves (all maps $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$) are of the shape that you and me have in mind---i.e., a curly line? How do we know, for example, that no curve ($[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$) has thickness?

Comment: I think that defining a curve as a curly line is one thing and defining it as a continuous map $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is another thing. The only thing that must be done is to relate these two things.